# Is open graph facebook login api currently working?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We are experiencing a failure of the old v2 facebook login interface.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/506823259335622?browse=search_50895412246979226453540

I am trying to find out if the open graph version of this interface is working as of 10/25 10am PST.

Comment: Per the response on that bug report, this is likely intentional, those endpoints were scheduled for removal about a year ago as far as i remember

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/506823259335622?browse=search_50895412246979226453540

Answer (score 1):

you will need to update the library with the new files for PHP SDK to work
check out this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/506823259335622?browse=search_50895412246979226453540)